# Magento 2 Scope Interface Model

Tags: magento2, system.xml, stores, system-config, scopeinterface

I have recently gone through magento's core `ScopeInterface` file which is located in `Magento\Store\Model`.

[image]

My question is why magento define `SCOPE_STORES` & `SCOPE_STORE` similar as `WEBSITE` and for `GROUP`.

Whenever i want to get data with scopeConfig how can i get (means if i want website data then `SCOPE_WEBSITE` or `SCOPE_WEBSITES`, which constant i have to use) ?

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_PRODUCT_MAX_QTY,ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITES);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do the same thing, if you check the following class:

```
Magento\Framework\App\Config::getValue()
```

The following code is pretty self-explanatory:

```
if ($scope === 'store') {
    $scope = 'stores';
} elseif ($scope === 'website') {
    $scope = 'websites';
}
```